# Unexpected output from python tkinter "calculator"

Tags: python, tkinter, error-handling

**here is the code**

```
from tkinter import*


def final_calculation():
    entryField.delete(0,'end') 
    Wood = entryWood.get()
    Steal = entrySteal.get()
    output_wood = (Wood *wood_c02)
    output_steal = (Steal * steal_c02 )
    final = (output_steal + output_wood *c02_coal)
    entry.set(final)


steal_c02 = int (5.5)
wood_c02 = int (1.2)
c02_coal = int (0.94)


root = Tk()
root.configure(background="black")
root.title("C02 caculator")
root.resizable(1,0)
root.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(1,weight=1)



entry = StringVar()
entryField = Entry(root, textvariable=entry,background="white",foreground="black",justify=CENTER)
entryField.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=2,sticky=W+E)
entryField.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)


labelWood = Label(root, text="Amount of wood",background="black",foreground="grey90")
labelWood.grid(row=1,column=0, sticky=E)

labelSteal = Label(root, text="Amount of steal",background="black",foreground="grey90")
labelSteal.grid(row=2,column=0, sticky=E)

entryWood = Entry(root,background="grey80",foreground="black")
entryWood.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky=W)

entrySteal = Entry(root,background="grey80",foreground="black")
entrySteal.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky=W)

button = Button(root, text="caculate C02", command= final_calculation)
button.grid(row=3, columnspan=2)





root.mainloop()
```

Press run and all is fine. Until you calculate the sum what redissolves in a issue, that is the second input is duplicated 5 times and that is displayed as the output, any help would be well helpful.

kind regards:49.95

Comment: Your variables are strings, not integers. You have to convert them: `Wood = int(entryWood.get()) ....`

Comment: thank you  that fixes part of the issue but its still only * the sencond number by 5

Comment: int(5.5) => 5. You probably want float() here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting mixed up in data types. Let's go through your code.

Here, you're converting decimal numbers to `int`. An integer is a rounded number (e.g. 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...). When you do `int(5.5)` you basically remove all info behind the decimal point:

```
steal_c02 = int (5.5) # = 5
wood_c02 = int (1.2) # = 1
c02_coal = int (0.94) # = 0
```

What you get from the Entry widgets are string objects. Although they might contain numbers, they are treated as text, not as numbers.
For example

```
Wood = entryWood.get() # Wood = '10'
Steal = entrySteal.get() # Steal = '1.5'
output_wood = (Wood *wood_c02)
```

Because `Wood = '10'` and `wood_c02 = 1`, you're multiplying a string with an integer. This works, but doesn't do what you're expecting. When in python you do `'a'*5`, you get `'aaaaa'`. So in this case `Wood *wood_c02` is `'10'*1` which is `'10'`

```
output_steal = (Steal * steal_c02 )
```

Here `Steal = '1.5'` and `steal_c02 = 5` and the same applies: `Steal * steal_c02` is `'1.5'*5` which is `'1.51.51.51.51.5'`

```
final = (output_steal + output_wood *c02_coal)
```

Here `output_steal = '1.51.51.51.51.5'`, `output_wood = '10'` and `c02_coal = 0`. `'10'*0 = ''` and `'1.51.51.51.51.5' + '' = '1.51.51.51.51.5'`, which you put in `final`.

---

You want to calculate with numbers, not strings, so you should convert your entry contents to numbers (do keep in mind that this wil fail if the input can not be converted to a number)

```
Wood = float(entryWood.get())
Steal = float(entrySteal.get())
```

You also want `steal_c02`, `wood_c02` and `c02_coal` to be decimal numbers, so don't convert them to integers:

```
steal_c02 = 5.5
wood_c02 = 1.2
c02_coal = 0.94
```

Comment: god bless your sweet sole